# how to calculate the datetime difference in microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns with datetime values in this format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.How do i calculate the difference between two columns in minutes and show a value if it exceeds certain minutes. For example if the difference of column B - A is less than 5 minutes, than it should show 'ok' else it should show 'fail'. Example

```
     A                      B                       C
8/5/2015  3:25:00 PM      8/5/2015  3:35:00 PM     Fail
```

Comment: Does this need to be robust over timezone changes, leap seconds, etc?

Comment: @PhilH Wow you're amazing like the kid in high school physics class who was adjusting for relativity when the teacher expected a Newtonian answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is needed is this formula:

`=IF((B1-A1)*1440<5,"OK","Fail")`

`(B1-A1)*1440` returns the number of minutes difference.

We're assuming that the second time is greater than the first. (And also assuming the same time zone.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hour(), Minute() Day() and month() functions to create an amalgam formula - it doesn't seem particularly sensible to do with numbers alone using cell-INT(cell).